# Unix command to list all directories larger than 10mb

Tags: unix, bash, shell

Is this possible, and what would the command be?

Comment: Do you mean like, all directories (regardless of at what depth)? Do you mean containing 10mb in the directory itself, or 10 mb in the directory or any subdirectory?

Comment: all directories at any depth, and the the total file size next to each directory would include it's sub directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`du` is the easiest way. Grab the directories of interest with perl.

```
du -m . | perl -ne '@l = split();print "@l\n" if $l[0]>=10'
```

Answer (score 9):

```
du -k /<root-of-interest> | sort -n
```

Then look at the tail for the large directories. You want all that are report greater than 10000.

Comment: du is the way to go. du|xdu makes it more visibile too..

Comment: I might type "du --max-depth=1 | sort -g | less" but that's just a personal preference.  Of course the "max-depth" flag only exists in GNU du.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
find {/path/to/directory} -type f -size +{file-size-in-kb}k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $8 ": " $5 }'
```

Remember to don´t put the {}'s.

In your case do like this:

```
find / -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $8 ": " $5 }'
```

Comment: this finds files, not directories

Comment: Ops, sorry, i didn't see. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The `du` answers above are closer to what you want, but you might also want to try out [kdirstat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/). Its a cool gui tool that shows all your dirs, what's in them, what the content is, and has various tools to delete or move files. There's even Windows ([WindDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)) and MacOSX ([Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/)) clones.