# How to find the largest file in a directory?

Tags: unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix command to list all directories larger than 10mb](https://superuser.com/questions/61500/unix-command-to-list-all-directories-larger-than-10mb)

How to find the largest file in a directory?

Comment: Related [Unix command to list all directories larger than 10mb](http://superuser.com/questions/61500/unix-command-to-list-all-directories-larger-than-10mb)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - the other wants large directories, this one wants large files.

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to use `ls`, sorted by size:

```
ls -S
```

To get the biggest one, use `head`:

```
ls -S | head -1
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're in the directory already:

```
du -a | sort -nr | head -1
```

Comment: Sizes for subdirectories are also calculated. Maybe you should mention that -- I'm not sure which approach the OP prefers.

Comment: Had it in there originally, figured it was logical to leave it in case one of the directories is large as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the find command to do this work.

Let **DIR** is the directory in which you want to find the largest file, run the following command:

```
find DIR/ -type f -size +5000k
```

This will list the files whose size greater than 5MB. You can adjust this value (ie. option size) according to your need.

If you want to check the files under this DIR only, use the below one. You can adjust the maxdepth value to check in subfolder.

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +5000k
```

Comment: this is nice.  It would be even nicer if there was a way to show the size for each one found